# Method of characteristics for system of linear transport equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, hyperbolic-equations, linear-pde

If I have a system of pde
$$\begin{cases} 
u_t+v_x=0\\
v_t+u_x=0\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x), v(x,0)=v_0(x)\end{cases}$$ 
how to extend the idea of method of characteristics to this situation? How do I parametrize the initial data and write the explicit solution to the problem for all $x$ and $t$ in terms of the functions $u_0$ and $v_0$?

Comment: A great solution to method of characteristics for a system of PDEs is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799360/method-of-characteristics-for-a-system-of-pdes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system rewrites as ${\bf u}_t + {\bf M}\, {\bf u}_x = {\bf 0}$ with ${\bf u} = (u,v)^\top$. We [diagonalize the matrix](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%7D%7D) as ${\bf M} = {\bf S}\, {\bf J}\, {\bf S}^{-1}$ where $\bf J$ is diagonal. Setting ${\bf v} = {\bf S}^{-1}{\bf u}$, one obtains a diagonal system ${\bf v}_t + {\bf J}\, {\bf v}_x = {\bf 0}$ which rows can be solved independently by using the method of characteristics. Then, $\bf u$ is deduced from ${\bf u} = {\bf S}\,{\bf v}$. Here, we find
\begin{aligned}
u(x,t)&= \frac{1}{2}\big(u_0(x-t)+u_0(x+t)\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(v_0(x-t)-v_0(x+t)\big)\\
v(x,t)&= \frac{1}{2}\big(v_0(x-t)+v_0(x+t)\big)+\frac{1}{2}\big(u_0(x-t)-u_0(x+t)\big)
\end{aligned}
This method works only for linear first-order systems ${\bf u}_t + {\bf M}\, {\bf u}_x = {\bf 0}$, which matrix $\bf M$ can be diagonalized in $\Bbb R$ (linear hyperbolic systems).