# Solving a linear system of first order PDE - what happens if the eigenvalues are complex?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, linear-pde

I am trying to solve the following linear system of 2 PDE's in 3 variables:
$$u_t-u_x+v_y=0$$
$$v_t-u_y-v_x=0$$
With initial condition $u(x,y,0)=a(x,y),v(x,y,0)=b(x,y)$. In matrix form, I can write this system as:

$-\begin{pmatrix}u_x\\v_x\end{pmatrix}\\ $$+ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u_y\\v_y\end{pmatrix}\\ $$+ \begin{pmatrix}u_t\\v_t\end{pmatrix}\\ $$= \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}\\$

I can diagonalize the matrix above and get:
$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\-i & i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-i & 0 \\0 & i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\-i & i\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$
Thus, I can define $\begin{pmatrix}f\\g\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\-i & i\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$, multiply both sides by $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\-i & i\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$ and get the separated system:
$$-f_x-if_y+f_t=0$$
$$-g_x+ig_y+g_t=0$$
With initial condition:
$$f(x,y,0)=\frac{1}{2}(a(x,y)+ib(x,y))$$
$$g(x,y,0)=\frac{1}{2}(a(x,y)-ib(x,y))$$
So far, I am basically following the method from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799360/method-of-characteristics-for-a-system-of-pdes).
I can now solve this system via the standard method of characteristics and then go back to the original functions $u,v$. The only problem is, that since the new PDE I got has complex coefficients (due to the fact that the eigenvalues are complex), I get the following solution for $u$:
$$u(x,y,t)=\frac{1}{2}[a(x+t,y+it)+ib(x+t,y+it)+a(x+t,y-it)-ib(x+t,y-it)]$$
And the solution for $v$ is similar. This is no good, since $a,b$ are real functions, but in the solution I plug in a complex number (which is not in the domain of $a,b$).

Does anyone understand what the problem is? Will this happen for any system with complex eigenvalues? Does that mean that there is no solution in this case? Is there something I can do to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't included the coefficient matrix for $(u_{x}, v_{x})$ in your post above. It would be modified by the the matrix of eigenvectors from the diagonalisation of the coefficient matrix of $(u_{y}, v_{y})$ as well.

Comment: @mattos The coefficient matrices are minus the identity for $x$ and the identity for $y$, so I have not written them explicitly (and they are not affected by the diagonalization).

Comment: I don't understand why sorry. You have $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \vec{u}_{t} + \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \vec{u}_{x} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \vec{u}_{y} = \vec{0}$$ The only identity matrix is for the time derivative. The coefficient matrix for $\vec{u}_{x} = (u_{x}, v_{x})$ is not the identity.

Comment: @mattos You are right, I did not write this correctly in the first line. Fixed it.